# Can Windows Removable Storage send operator requests remotely?

Tags: windows-server-2003, removable-storage, windows

I'm playing around with a LTO tape-archival setup using Windows 2003 and Remote Storage Service. Everything's working great, but one thing I've noticed is that Operator Requests only seem to be able to be displayed on the desktop of the system. This means that in order to be notified about tape changes and other events, I basically need to be looking at the desktop the whole time.

Is there a way in which I could be notified of these events via email, or some other remote mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in functionality is limited to the "tray" icon and messages sent using the now-deprecated "Messenger" service. I doubt you're going to find much out there to help you, as Removable / Remote Storage was deprecated in Windows Server 2008 R2.

The built-in [Rss](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773194(WS.10).aspx) command-line tool for administering Removable / Remote Storage lacks any functionality to deal with operator requests. If you wanted to code something you might be able to use the [Removable Storage Manager APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540727(v=vs.85).aspx) to come up with something that waited for operator requests and fired-off notifications, but it would be strictly a "you build it" kind of effort. (As I'm looking at that API, though, it looks like it might not even have functionality to do what you want.)